# «Догма» и «догмат»: почему в русском языке существуют два слова, заимствованные от одного и того же греческого слова «δόγμα» в разных падежах?

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

> **Догмат**
> ...
> Происходит от др.-греч. δόγμα (род. п. δόγματος) «мнение;
> учение», из
> δοκέω «казаться; полагать, думать» (восходит к праиндоевр. *dek-
> «принимать»).
>
> *[[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)]*

Из этого следует, что «догма» происходит от именительного падежа древнегреческого слова «δόγμα», а «догмат» от родительного падежа — «δόγματος».

Но зачем заимствовать одно и то же слово в разных падежах? Есть ли разница в значениях слов «догма» и «догмат», и связана ли она с падежами греческого/древнегреческого языка?

В Википедии эти слова представляются как тождественные по значению:

> **До́гма́т**, или **до́гма** (др.-греч. δόγμα, δόγματος «мнение, решение,
> постановление») — утверждённое церковью положение вероучения,
> объявленное обязательной и неизменяемой истиной, не подлежащей критике
> (сомнению).
>
> *[[Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82)]*

В Толковом словаре Ожегова C. И.:

> **До́гма**, -ы, ж. Положение, принимаемое на веру за непреложную истину, неизменную при всех обстоятельствах. *Схоластические догмы.*
>
> **До́гмат**, -а, м. Основное положение в религиозном учении, считающееся (церковью) непреложной истиной и не подлежащее критике.
> *Догматы христианства.*

Из толкований Ожегова следует, что «догмат» это более религиозный термин, а «догма» — более философский? Но по сути одно и тоже?

А почему падежи разные? Ведь правильней было бы говорить просто «догма». «Догмат» («δόγματος») — это родильный падеж, и если перевести «δόγματος» на русский будет: *чего?* «догмы», например «содержание догмы». Почему родильный падеж «δόγματος» при заимствовании в русский язык перешёл в именительный: *что?* «догмат» и при это ещё существует заимствование именительного «δόγμα» — «догма»?

---

**Дополнение**

Может ли быть так, что слово «догмат» образовалось на самом деле нет от родительного падежа, как написано в словарях, а от множественного числа «δόγματα» — «догмы». Это слово ближе по звучанию к «догмат», потому что на конце нет «-ος». Например, в Википедии «Догматы Святой католической и апостольской (православной) церкви»:

> Τα **Δόγματα** της Αγίας Καθολικής και Αποστολικής (Ορθοδόξου) Εκκλησίας
>
> 1. Η πίστη και λατρεία της Αγίας Τριάδος (Πατρός, Υιού, Αγ. Πνεύματος)
> 2. Η θεϊκή φύση του Ιησού Χριστού
> 3. Η ανθρώπινη φύση του Ιησού Χριστού
>
>    ...
>    *[[Википедия](https://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9F%CF%81%CE%B8%CF%8C%CE%B4%CE%BF%CE%BE%CE%B7_%CE%95%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B1#%CE%A4%CE%B1_%CE%94%CF%8C%CE%B3%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B1_%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82_%CE%91%CE%B3%CE%AF%CE%B1%CF%82_%CE%9A%CE%B1%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AE%CF%82_%CE%BA%CE%B1%CE%B9_%CE%91%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%83%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AE%CF%82_(%CE%9F%CF%81%CE%B8%CE%BF%CE%B4%CF%8C%CE%BE%CE%BF%CF%85)_%CE%95%CE%BA%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B7%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B1%CF%82)]*

Может, заимствование было: «δόγματα» → «догматы», а потом уже от множественного числа в русском языке образовалось единственное: «догматы» → «догмат», по правилам русского языка?

Почему вообще составители словарей решили, что заимствование идёт от родительного падежа?

---

**Дополнение 2**

Сначала, в древнерусскую эпоху, появилось слово «догмат», а потом появилось слово «догма», зафиксированное у Даля в 1863 г.:

> **ДОГМАТ**
> ...
> В русском языке слова этой группы начали появляться еще в
> древнерусскую эпоху. Раньше других: догмат — «правило», «догмат» (в
> церковно-религиозном, богословском смысле) и догматисати — «выражать в
> виде догмата» (Срезневский, I, 689; Доп., 91). Позже появились в
> русском языке другие слова этой группы: *догматический* (Нордстет, I,
> 1780 г., 162), *догматизм* (Плюшар, XVII, 1841 г., 59), *догма* (Даль,
> I, 1863 г., 400), *догматичный* (Ушаков, I, 1935  г., 737). в В
> др.-рус. языке — из греческого. Ср. греч. δόγματ род. δόγματος (корень
> δόγ-) — «мнение», «учение», «положение» («тезис»), прил. δογματιχός —
> «догматический», «состоящий из догматов» (Синайский), сущ.
> δογματιχός — «догматик», δογματίζω — «утверждаю», «объявляю», «создаю
> догматы». Более поздние слова попали в русский язык при
> западноевропейском посредстве. Ср. франц. (с XVI в.) dogme,
> dogmatique, dogmatisme; нем. Dogma, Dogmátiker, Dogmatísmus,
> dogmátisch, dogmatisíeren. В западноевропейские языки эти греческие по
> происхождению слова попали при позднелатинском посред-стве. Семантика
> этих слов первоначально, в средние века, была и на Западе церковно-
> богословскан.
>
> *[Историко-этимологический словарь современного русского языка, П. Я. Черных]*

---

Исходя из словарной статьи можно предположить, что слово «догмат» было заимствовано непосредственно из греческого (не понятно только почему в родительном падеже), а «догма» попала в русский язык при западноевропейском посредстве.

---

**Дополнение 3**

Так же можно предположить, что:

«Догмат» был изначально заимствован при чтении религиозной литературы на греческом языке, поэтому он используется прежде всего в теологическом значении.

А вот более позднее заимствование «догма» осуществилось через западноевропейские языки, возможно, при чтении уже в большей степени философских трудов. Поэтому «догма» используется больше в отношении философских учений и т. п.

Comment: Это же разные слова. Догмат — это из какого-либо учения. А догма может быть и у человека (*положение, утверждение, не допускающее возражений*). Но, по словарям, одно значение у них совпадает, хотя в любом случае "догмат" звучит более серьёзно и глобально, то есть про какое-либо большое учение.

Comment: @oleedd Не понял вашего аргумента. Я не утверждал, что это одно и то же слово в русском языке. В том то и дело, что есть два слова, образованные путём заимствования из разных падежей одного греческого слова. А суть то одна и та же: неоспоримое данное, принимаемое на веру. Зачем заимствовать родительный падеж «догмат»?

Comment: @oleedd _«…в любом случае „догмат“ звучит более серьёзно и глобально, то есть про какое-либо большое учение»_ — В словарях есть примеры: _догмы римского права, схоластические догмы_. Таким образом, «догма» вполне применима к учениям.

Comment: В этом случае оно используется в одном же значении, только вот догмы меньше, чем догматы, как и сами эти учения. Про падеж не подскажу, но в русском языке есть тенденция к образованию вариантов для двух родов: *догма — ж.р., а догмат — м.р.* Может, просто совпадение с родительным падежом.

Comment: @oleedd Почему догмы меньше? Например, догмат христианства: триединство бога. Или догма стоиков: для хорошей жизни нужно жить в согласии с природой. Что больше, что меньше? Вы говорите, что у человека могут быть догмы. Но это скорее переносный смысл. Догма или догмат создаётся авторитетом, например, церковью и объявляется неоспоримой истиной. Может ли человек сам себе создать догму? (1/2)

Comment: @oleedd Догма похожа на аксиому, но аксиома основывается на чём-то очевидном, например: _какова бы ни была прямая, существуют точки, принадлежащие этой прямой, и точки, не принадлежащие ей_. А, например, _триединство бога_ — не очевидно, это то, что объявляется церковью неоспоримой истиной, в которую нужно просто поверить. Как человек сам себе может создать догму, мне не понятно. (2/2)

Comment: @oleedd Насчёт мужского и женского родов, вы, возможно, правы.

Comment: Конечно, догмат христианства больше (значимее). Просто такая разница ощущается между словами (соотношение в значимости). Человек может создать догму, по которой будет жить, которой будет придерживаться, которую будет советовать другим (см. словарное значение в первом комментарии). Сталкивался с подобным употреблением. Не зря у этого слова два значения, а не одно, как у догмата.

Comment: @oleedd _«Просто такая разница ощущается между словами (соотношение в значимости)»._ А что даёт такое ощущение? Мужской род?

Comment: Нет, если знаешь слова, то можешь объяснить разницу между ними.

Comment: @oleedd _«Конечно, догмат христианства больше (значимее)»_ А что придаёт ему значимость? Ведь на самом деле не известно правда ли это вообще. Догмат о триединстве Бога содержит логическое противоречие: 1=3. Конечно, можно сравнить, например, с водой, которая может быть жидкостью, льдом и паром, но при этом оставаться водой. Но с триединством бога не всё так просто, да и среди христиан есть сомневающееся, потому что это, насколько я знаю, прямо не указано в Библии, а является скорее выводом людей.

Comment: @oleedd Значимость определяется способностью оказывать влияние на что-то. На что влияет, принимаем мы догмат о триединстве Бога или нет?

Comment: Значимость во влиянии на мир, на жизнь людей.

Comment: @oleedd _«Нет, если знаешь слова, то можешь объяснить разницу между ними»._ Но вы же пишете, что _«„догмат“ **звучит** более серьёзно и глобально»_. А почему он так звучит? Из-за мужского рода?

Comment: Просто так понимаю разницу, это не связано с родом. "Звучит более..." (не идеально выразился) — такой смысл воспринимается, когда слышишь это слово. Поразмыслил и ещё нашёл разницу. Догмат — часто про фундамент какого-либо учения, а догма — часто закономерность или принцип, по которому рекомендуется что-либо делать. Догмат — часто непрозрачный для понимания (требуется много дополнительного текста, чтоб разъяснить все детали, что сказывается на отличии в размере), а догма — более прозрачна для понимания.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ответы на многие вопросы **можно найти в словаре**.

ДОГМА, -ы; ж. [от греч. dógma – мнение, постановление, учение] 1. Положение, принимаемое за непреложную истину, неизменную при всех обстоятельствах. Схоластические догмы. 2. обычно мн.: догмы, догм. Основные положения какого-л. учения. Догмы римского права. Церковные догмы.

ДОГМАТ;  -а; м. [от греч. dógma (dogmátos)] 1. Основное положение в религиозном вероучении, принимаемое на веру и не подлежащее критике. 2. =Догма (1 зн.).

Из словаря следует,  что слово «догмат» (от  dogmátos)  имеет более узкое значение, связанное с религией, но в значении «догма» **тоже используется**.

2. Догма, догмат.  **Многозначный суффикс АТ** входит в словообразовательную систему **современного** русского языка и может присоединяться непосредственно к имени существительному (ректор – ректорат, адрес – адресат).   Такая зависимость подсказывает нам  **частное**  (религиозное, в данном случае) значение слова «догмат», хотя слова заимствовались **независимо** друг от друга.

Когда заимствованное слово **осваивается в языке**, то нет необходимости **во всем следовать источнику**, в том числе его грамматическим формам. Для нас важнее, насколько форма  этого слова (ее морфемный состав) соответствует смыслу, **указанному в словаре  на текущий период**.

3. Эти слова появились **еще в древнерусскую эпоху**. Догматизм как определенный метод мышления связан с использованием неизменных  и недоказанных понятий. Наибольшую силу он набирает в Римской империи в христианскую эпоху.
4. Таким образом, **философское** значение более характерно для общего определения (догма), а  догмат в большей степени  конкретен и поэтому обычно связан **с религией.**

Comment: Проголосовал за ваш ответ.

Comment: По содержанию. Пункт 1: Я видел эти определения в словаре, но взял более простое толкование из словаря Ожегова, чтоб не перегружать вопрос; в Ожегове нет совпадающего значения, а отличающиеся есть. Пункт 4: Я к такому же выводу и пришёл, у меня в вопросе есть текст: _«Из толкований Ожегова следует, что „догмат“ это более религиозный термин, а „догма“ — более философский?»_

Comment: Спасибо, я добавила еще пару предложений. Я предпочитаю пользоваться словарями РАН, так как они обновляются практически ежегодно

Comment: Пункт 2. Про суффикс «-ат» интересно. В [Викисловаре](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) тоже написано: *Корень: -догм-; суффикс: -ат*. Но я не пойму, ведь если заимствование было от «δόγματος», то корень тут δόγμα-, а -τος — окончание родительного падежа. Откуда взялся русский суффикс «-ат»?

Comment: Возможно, здесь указано современное толкование морфемного разбора, когда АТ вписывается в наше понимание этого слова. Тогда  способ заимствования нас уже меньше интересует, это уже история.

Comment: Вы про словари на Грамоте? С чего вы взяли, что они обновляются практически ежегодно? Словарь Кузнецова там — 2014 года (и то не факт, описание нечёткое). В орфографическом год не указан.

Comment: Вы много написали, в том числе определения, но мой вопрос касался больше не значений слов, а заимствования в разных падежах. А это так и осталось загадкой. Почему всё-таки заимствовали родительный падеж? Безграмотность? Но вряд ли люди, которые могли читать на греческом, не могли отличить именительный от родильного.

Comment: «Вряд ли люди, которые могли читать на греческом, не могли отличить именительный от родильного» — один падеж от другого они, конечно, отличали, но не слишком ли много вы от них требуете, ожидая, что они, как заправские современные лингвисты, могли выделить в любом греческом слове корень, суффикс и окончание? Они могли решить, что «-ος» — окончание, а основа — «δόγματ». Тем более, что «догмат», будучи словом мужского рода, смотрелся солиднее, чем «догма»: мужчина, как-никак! :)

Answer (score 0):

«Догма» — это «догмат» в отрицательном смысле :)

> **Догма**
>
> (...) Наиболее часто встречается теологическое использование термина, но имеется также множество священных и квазинаучных догм. В науке термин всегда имеет явно отрицательный оттенок. Отличается от несколько более нейтрального термина «доктрина», обозначающего обширные теоретические положения, которые относятся к недоступным верификации утверждениям и которые поддерживаются за счёт всё ещё невыполненного обещания о будущем их подтверждении (например, фрейдистская доктрина, бихевиористическая доктрина) (...)
>
> https://psychology_pedagogy.academic.ru/6001/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: А вы могли бы дать более развёрнуто свою мысль?

Comment: Думаю, мог бы :)

Comment: А у догмы есть положительный смысл? Вот уж не думала. :)

Comment: @Sharon Тут наоборот утверждается, что у «догмы» отрицательный смысл. Но догма тут используется в религиозном и сродных значениях; тот же смысл, что и у «догмата». Отрицательный смысл потому, что что-то предлагается принять слепо на веру, что противоречит научному подходу. Поэтому написано: _«В науке термин всегда имеет явно отрицательный оттенок»_.

Comment: В вашем ответе «догма» не противопоставляется догмату, а используется в том же теологическом значении, что и основное значение у «догмата».

Comment: Взяли слово dogmátos – вот и получился догмат, заимствование способом транслитерации, по буквам.  Падежи в таких случаях вряд ли учитываются. (Кстати, чем отличаются эти формы?)  Оба слова могут использоваться с одинаковым значением, но основное значение указывается в словаре первым. Поэтому догма - учение в общем смысле, а догмат  в более конкретном.  Здесь мы уже ориентируемся на наличие АТ в слове догмат.